# C++ Eigen: recursive functions accepting any matrix class

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to have a recursive function

```
template <typename Derived>
void f(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m)
{
    size_t blockRows = ...
    size_t blockCols = ...
    ....
    f(m.block(0, 0, blockRows, blockCols));
}
```

This unfortunately results in an infinite compile time recursion.

The first call would be to

```
f<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> >
```

The second would be to

```
f<Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>, ... > >
```

The third call would be to

```
f<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>, ... >, ... > >
```

Every time a block of block is requested.

What is the best practice to implement recursive functions in Eigen, which still work on any Eigen matrix type?

I think, I should use some type, that still wraps the same piece of memory, but is not an expression template and it is evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your recursive block to an `Eigen::Ref` to avoid the infinite type instantiation:

```
Ref<MatrixXd> bl = m.block(0, 0, blockRows, blockCols);
f(bl);
```

To stay fully generic, you can replace `MatrixXd` by `typename Derived::PlainObject`.

Comment: I would assume you ment PlainObjectBase, because there is not PlainObjectType. But this does not work as well. I have to change the signature of f to void f(Eigen::Ref<Derived>& m) to make it work.But then it fails with matrices of fixed size. In that case m.block(..) has different dimensions from Derived. So the block should be assigned to a matrix, that is the same as Derived, but has a dynamic size.

Comment: It's `PlainObject`, not `PlainObjectBase`. I fixed the answer.